# How do I call a variable to get value from Firebase database?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

My database structure is the following:

```
"Menus" : {
    "Day1" : {
        "mealDes" : "delicious Thai food",
        "date" : "2016.10.20",
        "mealname" : "kakoon"
    },
```

And my code:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Menus/Day1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
    if let snapDict = snap.value as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject>{
        let date = snapDict["date"] as! String

        let OrderInfo = DataService.ds.REF_ORDER
        let USERUID = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid
        let userinfo = OrderInfo.child(date).child(USERUID).child("data")

        userinfo.child("address").setValue("SomeRandomAddress")
        userinfo.child("phonenumber").setValue("666888")
    }
})
```

I know I get "date is 2016.10.20" if I print (date)

but what if I want to set 2016.10.20 as value to other node?

Can I set a variable to represent the whole code above and get the date value?

Like if I want to set the value "2016.10.20" to node "theOtherDate"

Is there anyway I could do the following in the other function?

```
child("theOtherDate").setValue(date)
```